# Как разделить значения, содержащиеся в одной ячейке DataFrame, так чтобы они оказались записаны в разных строках

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется файл с названием компании и её мобильными номерами. Все номера содержатся в одной ячейке, соответствующей 1 компании и разделены запятой.
[image: Пример необработанных данных]
Нужно сделать так, чтобы эти номера оказались в разных ячейках, относящейся к одной компании.
[image: Пример обработанных данных]
Файл очень большой, так что вручную это делать очень долго. Пытался автоматизировать процесс с помощью python, в частности pandas, однако недостаточно опытен в таких вещах)) Буду рад любой помощи, всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: Рады будем увидеть ваши попытки решения этой задачи.

Comment: Я могу просплитовать номера и добавить их в новые колонки, однако как потом перенести их в строки и добавить к соответствующему названию компании у меня не выходит.
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': ['+7495,+1928,+7234', '+7495,+1928', ''], 'company': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df1=df['number'].str.split(',',expand=True)
df1['company'] = df.company

Answer (score 1):

Что касается вашего примера из комментариев, можно сделать так:

```
df['number']=df['number'].str.split(',') 
df = df.explode('number')
```

А что касается исходного вопроса, то у вас там скрины из экселя, это не даёт представления, как выглядит соответствующий этому экселю датафрейм, поэтому ничего толком сказать нельзя пока датафрейм не будет показан в вопросе.

Comment: круто! это почти что то, что нужно. Осталось только сгруппировать данные, т.е. чтобы несколько ячеек с номерами соответствовали своему названию компании.

Comment: @Георгий То есть чтобы как в экселе были объединены ячейки? Такого в `pandas` нельзя сделать. А так то компания соответствует в моём примере или я не понял что вы хотите.

Comment: Да, нужно, чтобы были объединены ячейки, т.е  одна ячейка с названием компании и ей соответствовали номера компании в отдельных ячейках. Очень жаль, что pandas не имеет такой функции(( Большое спасибо за ответы!